# War "Betha" jemals eine zulässige Schreibweise für den griechischen Buchstaben β?

Tags: word-usage, difference, history

Einer meiner Lehrer schwankte heute zwischen *Beta* und *Betha* als Schreibweise für den griechischen Buchstaben β. Wir sollten das doch mal kurz googeln. Gesagt, getan. Natürlich ist [laut Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beta) Beta die richtige Schreibweise.

Doch ich fand auch [diese Tabelle](http://www.derkleinegarten.de/mehr-infos-bilder/symbollexikon/viereck.html), in der *Betha* mit H geschrieben wurde.

[image]

Und ich dachte auch immer, dass es zwei Varianten der Aussprache gäbe. Zwei Beispiele:

1. Einzelne Entwicklungsstufen einer Software werden häufig als Alpha-Version und Beta-Version bezeichnet. Beta wird hier mit normal betontem e gesprochen.
2. Im Gegensatz dazu werden Winkel häufig mit α, β, γ bezeichnet und β wird mit kurzem e gesprochen, also geschrieben wie Betha (oder überspitzt: 'Betta').
   <sup>Stellt euch einfach euren ehem. Mathe-Lehrer vor, wie er euch den Pythagoras beibringen will und wie er die Winkel aussprach.</sup>

Und zum Schluss noch ein [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Betha%2CBeta&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBetha%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeta%3B%2Cc0) um die historische Häufigkeit in Büchern von Beta und Betha gegenüberzustellen. Der Ausreißer in der Zeit des 2. Weltkriegs lässt sich vielleicht durch die geringe Gesamtanzahl an Büchern aus dieser Epoche erklären, wodurch Einzelnennungen schwerer ins Gewicht fallen.

[image]

Meine Frage ist: War *Betha* jemals eine zulässige Schreibweise?

Answer (score 8):

Ich denke, der Lehrer hat sich verschrieben. Die Treffer aus der Zeit vor 1945 scheinen sich fast alle auf den *Namen* Betha zu beziehen, der mit dem Buchstaben nichts zu tun hat. Die Idee der "zulässigen" Schreibweise setzt sich erst 19. Jahrhundert durch ([siehe bspw. hier zu den Orthographiekonferenzen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1876)), vorher variierten die Schreibungen ziemlich stark. Heute ist generell so, daß mit dem deutschen "th" ein Theta im griechischen Wortstamm wiedergegeben wird, während ein "t" dem griechischen Tau entspricht. Beta schrieben schon die alten Griechen mit Tau, deshalb schreiben wir es heute mit "t".

Comment: Und die verlinkte Tabelle ist demnach falsch? Wenn man die Quelle anschaut, scheint der Autor kein unbewanderter Mensch zu sein. (In dem Artikel geht um die Herkunft von β)

Comment: @nixda: er kann sich verschrieben haben, weil auf der selben Zeile der _hebräische_ Buchstabe [_bet_ oder _beth_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bet_%28letter%29) steht, den ich selber bis jetzt eigentlich nur als _beth_ kannte.

Comment: @WalterTross http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bet_%28letter%29 sagt, dass `beth` dem Tiberischen Hebräisch entspringt. Möglicherweise bezogen sich die alten Akademiker häufig darauf, weswegen `beth` statt `bet` zur verbreiteten Schreibung wurde. Die heutige Standardschreibung scheint aber tatsächlich `bet` zu sein.